# Smart contract call - Error 3090004: Missing required authority

Tags: smart-contract, cleos, permissions

I'm getting this error: "Error 3090004: Missing required authority" when I try to call contract method. Jungle testnet is used.

That is the method:

```
      //@abi action
      void add(account_name name, uint64_t owner) {
           ordertable orders(_self, _self);
           orders.emplace(owner, [&](auto& order) {
                order.owner = owner;
           });
       }
```

Contract is compiled and deployed. I'm using that:

```
cleos  -u https://jungle.eosio.cr:443  set contract myaccount  ./ ./order.wast ./order.abi
```

And contract is called with that:

```
cleos -u https://jungle.eosio.cr:443 push action myaccount add '["myaccount","2"]' -p myaccount@active
```

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: first argument to `emplace` is the payer, while in your case is just number 2. try `_self` or `name` instead of `owner` as the first argument

Comment: @confused00, it works! Thank you man!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the first argument passed to the `emplace()` method in the multi-index structure is not an account you have permission to use as a payer.

According to [the docs](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cpp/reference#emplace), the parameters are as follows:

> Parameters
>
> - **payer** - Account name of the payer for the Storage usage of
>     the new object
> - **constructor** - Lambda function that does an in-place initialization of
>     the object to be created in the table

Thus, the first parameter should be the `account_name` of the account that's expected to pay, while in your example you pass the `uint64_t` 2.

You can use `name` if you want the account calling the function to pay for RAM to store the new row, or you can use `_self` if you want the smart contract creator to pay for the RAM usage.